# Getting text from Edit Text inside Text Input Layout that has a prefix

Tags: android, gettext, prefix, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am having a Text Input Edit Layout with a TextInputEditText that has a prefix of +254

Below is the code of the Text Input Layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_phone_number"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_text_view_login_description"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:prefixText="+254">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_phone_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The problem am having is that when am getting Text from the text input edit text its not getting the prefix its only getting the text entered. How can i get the whole text with the prefix

Below is how i am getting the text

```
etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim()
```

I have tried removing the trim() but its not getting the prefixText

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Prefix text using `getPrefixText()` method on your 'TextInputLayout' object (til_phone_number) ..

link:- https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#getPrefixText()